# Solve an Inglenook Sidings Puzzle

Tags: code-golf, game, puzzle-solver

## Solve an Inglenook Sidings Puzzle

### Background

The [Inglenook Sidings Puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inglenook_Sidings) is a shunting/switching yard puzzle by Alan Wright for model railroading. The rules for the puzzle are as follows: ([Source](http://www.wymann.info/ShuntingPuzzles/Inglenook/inglenook-rules.html))

- Form a departing train consisting of 5 out of the 8 wagons sitting in the sidings.
- The 5 wagons are selected at random.
- The train must be made up of the 5 wagons in the order in which they are selected.

You have 4 sidings:

- The "main line", which is 5 cars long (labeled `B`)
- Two spurs coming off the main line, each of which is 3 cars long (`C` and `D`)
- A yard lead, which is 3 cars long. (`A`)

[image: The Inglenook Sidings Puzzle layout]

<sup>(Source: http://www.wymann.info/ShuntingPuzzles/Inglenook/inglenook-trackplan.html)</sup>

### The Challenge

Given the ordered list of cars in the train, generate the movements of the cars needed to form the train. *These moves need not be the shortest solution.*

#### The sidings

- Each siding can be considered to be an ordered list of cars.
- Each car can be represented by one of eight unique symbols, with an additional symbol the engine.
- Cars can only be pulled and pushed as if it were coupled to an engine on the `A`-direction (i.e. you cannot access a car from the middle of a siding without needing to remove the head/tail ends first.)
- For this challenge, the starting state will be the same for all cases (where `E` is the engine, and digits are the 8 cars):

```
A E[ ] -- 12345 B
        \-- 678 C
         \- [ ] D
```

- **The puzzle is considered solved if all five cars in the `B`-siding are in the same order as the input car list.**

#### Input

Input is an ordered list of five car tags representing the requested train.
The car tags should be a subset of any 8 unique elements, e.g. `{a b c d e f g h}` and `{1 two 3 4 five six 7 eight}` are allowed sets of car tags, but `{a b 3 3 e f g h}` is not allowed because not all elements are unique.

#### Output

Output is a list of moves for the cars.
Examples of a single move can be:

```
B123A // source cars destination
BA123 // source destination cars
"Move from siding B cars 123 to siding A."
```

Among other formats. **The source, destination, and cars moved should be explicit, and explained in whatever move format you choose.**

If it is unambiguous that a cut of cars (a set of cars grouped together) moves unchanged from one siding to another, you can omit a step to the intermediate track, e.g. `1ba 1ad 2ba 2ad => 1bd 2bd`, e.g. `123ba 123ad 67ca 67ab 8ca 8ab => 123bd 67cb 8cb`, e.g. `5db 5ba => 5da`. All of these cases can be compacted due to a matching source-destination track, and the cut of cars moved doesn't change order. The test cases will use this compacted notation.

#### Movement Rules

The cars move similarly to real-life railroad cars: you usually can only access one end of the cut at a time. So, the following moves are **illegal** (assuming a starting state similar to the one described above):

```
1ba 2ba 1ad     // trying to access car 1 but car 2 is blocking access, since the last car on the cut is now 2: E12
12ba 21ad       // swapping the order of cars without any intermediate steps to swap them
12345ba 12345ad // trying to fit too many cars into a siding (5 > 3 for sidings A and D)
```

#### Additional Rules

- [Standard loopholes are forbidden](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default).
- [Input and output can be in any reasonable format.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code wins!

#### Test Cases

The moves in these testcases will be in the form `cars source destination`, separated by spaces. These are some possible solutions, and *not necessarily the shortest.*

```
Train -> Moves // comment
--------------
12345 ->  // empty string, no moves needed
21345 -> 1bd 2bd 21db
14385 -> 123bd 67cb 8cb 867ba 67ac 4bc 8ab 123da 3ab 2ad 4ca 14ab
43521 -> 123ba 3ad 4ba 24ad 1ab 2db 215ba 5ad 21ab 5db 43db
86317 -> 67ca 7ad 8cd 6ac 8dc 1bd 23ba 3ad 45ba 5ac 3db 5cb 1db 4ac 7da 1bd 5bd 3bd 7ab 35db 1da 3bd 5bd 1ab 53da 3ab 25ad 4cd 86cb
```

#### Tips

- All Inglenook Sidings Puzzles are solvable if and only if the inequality \$(h-1)+m_1+m_2+m_3\ge w+M\$ is true, where \$h\$ is the capacity of the yard lead, \$m_1, m_2, m_3\$ are the capacities of the sidings, \$w\$ is the number of wagons, and \$M = \max(h-1, m_1, m_2, m_3)\$. For the initial state for the challenge, this is \$w = 8, h=m_1=m_2=3, m_3=5\$. (https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07970)
- You can only take and give cars from the end of the cut facing the switches, similarly to a stack.
- [A program to test your program output](https://tio.run/##nVVNj5swEL3zK0bpgaBlozUfSYSUSrvbHivl0BtCyICjWiVAsVNpVfW3pzMYSMjHtioSwbyZefM8niHNm/5WV/7xKPdN3WpQb8rql03TykoDV7DdDtihkloLpS3LKsQOGt4q8aX@KdR8T78RKN068PgRbH1oShGXUukYWRIXuqVB0cmF4SdJEjuyAK@OAjbmuVBNKfXc7siczr6TFS/RToRz6cCubkGCrExA/JQk1zQxS3omw9EKfWgrQ@VC3MmOo0cPBXZLXC0OTSPauTMgbERMSkLHrElfiaKmMsx1y/PvykRGQxGm27Uds9uct2leH7DCGyhFZZQ8JUamqg9tLvpN4B46sMDCo24t62qweMbyAbqzmo@cbs/gngcZarkb2TdgP/e1HwpXILPZRGy8kpjE9RC6J3i8J@1RMkZPo65povd4DI0olfirnOgi6F9yX@rFGkyKeVGIPvrM5Yxzgj4YlTfU3@Ywe3q4ZcVGykuuFHxF0MzUMG0Lgl65En3rUMMRnhLdXuDBK1HunFNyatNSVl2b4kQvlC5kdTKf9KGkX7PnWQRx4k7Mp2v2QmbmgueC70LgQnjf95V8ly6sXFjf9/rUJfw9MZsGJtGLFsdENjhuE4d@ZIfpPvv0UJBzg2zWhUQz18ROXbbbhfnAjT35YicXGS@HPbrakGEgo3PHZtPSdkFUxcYevmTn140vx7XTpVrHst43Xwv5vxpcmWlYblAZvylGTbnAjhat/vzjwMtzmvFMLAuHMU0rvhdp2k1imu65rNK0H8hxCAidO8cj8/wgpL8Fy2P9imUFeHSzIrNY4K8N6vmILVd5Bmu6l6uM4yvPIchyWPOMPAoOPq48XkCQc2ABz6zADz02MJAdbfj0Alwwci7wZiFCIaekCIUIBT5mXy99tqJYzMthhfZ1jiIw6brIjdCR0zDkgHEQokJGJPi@QlHkGeJNW1hhAp8yMFLbG7qso/yw04/Jlnn2Bw), input format is `final_state -> [cars_moved][source][destination]`.

Comment: So my understanding is that `67ca 7ad` (in the last test case) is a compressed form of `67ca 67ad 6da`. But there _must_ be at least 2 empty slots on line D for this move to be valid because cars 6 and 7 have to be temporarily put there. Is that correct?

Comment: And when `8cd` is executed after `67ca 7ad`, car `6` is still attached to the locomotive, right?

Comment: You say (for the starting state): *where E is the engine* - but don't see an  *E* anywhere. Please explain.

Comment: @Arnauld `67ca 7ad` means that cars 6 and 7 from `c` to `a`, and car 7 by itself gets moved into `d`. The car counts for each siding is for the max number of cars that can *stay* there, since (in real life/on models) the switches take some space and you can "hold" cars on there, but not really because it's not a siding track.

Comment: @Arnauld part 2: yes, after `67ca 7ad` car 6 is still attached

Comment: @Noodle9 `E` is omitted because the loco doesn't count as a car; the moves only show car movements, and not engine movements. I'll add a note saying this in the main post

Comment: `a` can be safely interpreted as cars attached to the engine.  Alternatively (and more abstractly), all four can be interpreted as stacks where the only movement allowed is between `a` and one of the other three stacks.

Comment: This challenge seems hard enough that it'd be better as a [tag:code-challenge], instead of [tag:code-golf].

Answer (score 4):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 120 bytes

```
⊞υ⪪”←‴⧴ν↘pＧ8¡¶”¶Ｗ¬⊙υ№κθ«≔υη≔⟦⟧υＦηＦ⁴Ｆ…·¹Ｌ⁻§κλ Ｆ⎇λ¹…¹¦⁴¿¬‹№§κν μ⊞υ⊞ＯＥκ⎇⁼πλ◨✂ξμχ¹Ｌξ⎇⁼πν⁺⮌…§κλμ✂ξ⁰±μ¹ξ⁺⁺…§κλμ§βλ§βν»✂⊟Φυ№ιθ⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHda8IwEH9e/4qjTxfoYGrdBj6JbCCoK7q3dQ9ZjU1YTGuSOmXsb@@S1roPxgrJcdf7fdwl41RnBZV1nVSGYxXBqpTCYggAqer1B/EwVdc3t6lyhTCCMFUhIaPgjQvJABeFxbE6etykqJTF1wh2xH3wHlyMjRG58v@4Q3Tp03MElc83hQbkBJoYn@JUZbIyYs@WVOUMexHMmMotx7lQlcGxnao1O3gZSZwbCBuxBvrItKL6iDICBzvjY98gNq3XGTMGW6ffqNSJKoKtb@424eNDyTS1hcY5LX1rJ3K3q6g0WLY@ErpeipxbXEmRMTw4Imfiyh1yHuBAyF9wr524kXHJ9kwbhpNjJtmEF@XvYbee4CzgyBcsp5bhlngddzmFjqy5/mGKoCu9@NLPXPmdjoKPINFCdTMljuZeSMv012OL9rGbHY/quj/oxcP6ci8/AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Very brute force (spends most of its time shuffling the first wagon between sidings `a` and `b`) so can only solve simple cases on TIO. All moves are always between siding `a` and another siding. Moves list the wagons in the order that they enter the other siding, which for wagons leaving siding `a` is the reverse of what you might expect. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⪪”←‴⧴ν↘pＧ8¡¶”¶
```

Start with the initial position.

```
Ｗ¬⊙υ№κθ«
```

Repeat until a sequence of moves resulting in the desired position is found. (The code actually checks all sidings but only siding `b` can actually have that position of course.)

```
≔υη
```

Save the previously found positions.

```
≔⟦⟧υ
```

Start a new list of found positions.

```
Ｆη
```

Loop over the previously found positions.

```
Ｆ⁴
```

Consider each possible source siding.

```
Ｆ…·¹Ｌ⁻§κλ
```

Consider all of the wagons in that siding.

```
Ｆ⎇λ¹…¹¦⁴
```

For siding `a`, consider the other three sidings as a possible destination, otherwise consider siding `a` as a possible destination.

```
¿¬‹№§κν μ
```

Check whether the destination has enough room for the number of wagons being moved.

```
⊞υ⊞ＯＥκ⎇⁼πλ◨✂ξμχ¹Ｌξ⎇⁼πν⁺⮌…§κλμ✂ξ⁰±μ¹ξ⁺⁺…§κλμ§βλ§βν
```

Create an updated position with the wagons moved to the other siding, plus append the current move, and save that to the list of positions.

```
»✂⊟Φυ№ιθ⁴
```

Output the moves required to reach the desired position.

I've written a version which is somewhat faster but still only manages to solve `43521` because it cheats and ignores siding `c` if the input contains no digit above `5`. (The above version is so slow that even this optimisation doesn't help it.)

```
⊞υ⪪”←‴Fa×ι|”¶≔⮌υηＷ¬⊙η№κθ«≔ηζ≔⟦⟧ηＦζＦ⁴¿∧λ∨⁻λ²›⌈θ5«≔⁺§κ⁰§κλεＦ…·⌈⟦⁰⁻Ｌε⎇⊖λ³¦⁵⟧⌊⟦³Ｌε⟧«≔⊞ＯＥκ⎇⁼ξλ✂εμχ¹⎇ξν✂ε⁰μ¹⁺μ§βλδ¿¬№υ…δ⁴«⊞υ…δ⁴⊞ηδ»»»»✂⊟Φη№ιθ⁴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVLbToNAEH2Gr5jwNJusSa9q4lNTLzHx0qhvtg9Ix7JxWdoFaqvpt@MsK9hIQmAu58yZS5LGNsljXdezqkixkvC81qrEaG76g@FoPDenZ@dzE0lgTyTERTgpCrUy@ERbsgVhJSSk7P5MlSbAh7zEidljKmGaV6bEDwkbwQ98h8EvlGNfjGjN14VnCN5zC/gloPmOBKh3YK4lagmPFu@VqQr3P@CKN5biktgZ71RWZbhhXzSO2kIt9UwzZFLemiXtnJIepx2ZWrBNrrSvfWsSBqgtPcVmRR35a0@Cr35HZlWmSAx7IWtiu8dLSixlZEpioewfShgLsRANxMPZ1QEXrcJOIo/9cU02LnPXztrparmvNlWsC9w5pbwYrRJCkpBJ6LOk/pEKTjFHGT2f5MYhoRlC9tf4W9M4B5ZN54Ebs1ub3xdfwHSfaJqm@RqXEkbdTIOgPZH/CRd/0bSjPYTNewgP4cwqZvbqZoy6Vtotr7sR5W/Ec9X1aDge9OuTrf4B) Link is to verbose version of code.

The output of this version is not currently in a standard format, so I'll explain it here. Each line consists of a digit and a letter. The letter represents the other siding from or to which wagons are shunted to or from siding `a`. The digit represents the number of wagons that end up in siding `a`. Example:

```
    /12345/678/ Initial position
3b: 123/45/678/ Fill a with 3 wagons from b
0d: /45/678/123 Move all wagons from a to d
2b: 45//678/123 Fill a with 2 wagons from b
3d: 451//678/23 Fill a with 1 wagon from d
2b: 45/1/678/23 Move 1 wagon from a to b
3d: 452/1/678/3 Fill a with 1 wagon from d
1b: 4/521/678/3 Move 2 wagons from a to b
2d: 43/521/678/ Fill a with 1 wagon from d
0b: /43521/678/ Move 2 wagons from a to b
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python3, 1447 bytes:

```py
R=range
E=enumerate
F=lambda s,e,m:s+''.join(map(str,m))+e
U=lambda x:eval(str(x))
def C(w,m,o,c,e):
 if[]==c:yield w,m;return
 for x in o:
  for i,y in E(c):
   if len(w[x][1])<w[x][0]:W=U(w);M=U(m);W[x][1]=([y if x!=1 else(y,)]+W[x][1]if x else W[x][1]+[y]);M+=[F(W[e][2],W[x][2],[y])];yield from C(W,M,o,c[:i]+c[i+1:],e)
def V(w,m,t,c):
 if w[1][1][:len(j:=[i for i in w[1][1]if type(i)==tuple])]==j:
  B=0
  for W,M in C(w,m,{0,2,3}-{c},[i for[i]in j],1):
   B=1
   W,M=U(W),U(M);W[1][1]=W[1][1][len(j):];W[c][1]=(W[c][1][1:]if c else W[c][1][:-1]);M+=[F(W[c][2],'B',[t])];W[1][1]=[t]+W[1][1];yield W,M,1
  if not B:
   w[c][1].remove(t)
   for W,M in C(w,m,{0,2,3}-{c},[t],c):yield W,M,0
def f(t):
 w,m=[{0:3,1:[],2:'A'},{0:5,1:[*R(1,6)],2:'B'},{0:3,1:[6,7,8],2:'C'},{0:3,1:[],2:'D'}],[]
 if w[1][1]==t:return m
 T=t[:(r:=max(e)+1 if(e:=[i for i in R(5)if t[i]!=w[1][1][i]])else 5)]or t;W=w[1][1][:r]
 w[1][1]=w[1][1][r:]
 if(M:=W[:3][::-1]):w[3][1]+=M;m+=[F('B','D',M[::-1])]
 if(M:=W[3:]):w[0][1]+=M;m+=[F('B','A',M[::-1])]
 q=[(U(w),U(m),T)]
 while q:
  W,M,T=q.pop(0)
  if[]==T:return M
  if(O:=[i for i in[0,2,3]if W[i][1]and W[i][1][(0 if i else -1)]==T[-1]]):
   for W,M,I in V(W,M,T[-1],O[0]):q+=[(W,M,T[:-1]if I else T)]
  else:
   if(O:=[i for i in [0,2,3]if T[-1]in W[i][1]]):
    [c]=O;S=(W[c][1][:1]if c else W[c][1][-1:]);W[c][1]=(W[c][1][1:]if c else W[c][1][:-1])
    for W,M in C(W,M,{0,1,2,3}-{c},S,c):q+=[(W,M,T)]
 return m
```

Not the shortest solution, and can be golfed further, but produces output moves for all the test cases in 0.2 seconds. For input, it takes a list of the desired car order, and the output is a list with all the moves.

Move notation:

```
<source siding>[cars moved]<destination siding>
```

For example, `'B123D'` means "move cars 1, 2, and 3 from siding B to siding D.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVRNb@IwEL3zK9wT9maoElhaZNaH0m2lHlCllpaD5UM2mG0QSSCkBVTx29kZJynQrVZaCcnOmw/PezPDYlu8ZGmnt8j3@weVh@lv27hRNn1NbB4WtnGr5mHyaxKyFVhI5MprNs9nWZzyJFzwVZFDIoRnG0@120bat3BOFr4RojGxU3bN15BABhFYIRssnmqjVCS3sZ1PGJr6uS1e87TBplnONixOWYZu7iuGLX3f8IgiGcayuU35Wm@MDoz44S6@kWP1xNeiP8QjEf1xaVZcbylic6YCZucry7cgjFdZyeBQVgGe3hpM4Sl9y8faGt024Ex4ksn0y4qneZYgpzEMiZOWsfEiHXuBNMjPEX52hAuISrpsjdnpJ6n2mVQ6LskRtcqGXsV2YXkslCpeF3OL7yk1I9ID5Vdq4JMUUur57kMbOrvWe7SDMqGODVpnBoJSrIEK6MAolGUs4IkPSRv3nqpO7UoS0qAhKkWrLhoJYVVRrVEJylZwJFLkxGkOmqALEqhOjl9eda9EI7WoGsyYZgUbuALXZdLz3CbZm@WFIPDfRAtDqh5y@k7wKcZiRvRW@t2XHQikNtCWzavmDuNll4BvDzyAC@HwQYk7xwu4hJ5Dr49QB/xs7rD35riJ2B5ZzitLGmykCi15LlUSbrgVXoCe3J52@IF3BbUX23Om6lGIjRFO2K4w6Fj0xx8mmeOD9Ws1mEtXBR9K7JzsoJfrhFzrjptdNewnrinUDKwbhpXHUVhHugD/i4Crk4Cl0pz2CWibYETQ@iWeW7aktpHsI7U8X2QL7gvXU1roUS3L0EH8/kQF7ZpIAzVG7lhAmE7qq@Y@CRyXk9YKaPJHGmsx5RxXEwF3pOazWzxnhnvkIuQSaVQgEcBMd2UmV7i7Vv8dn2pih6JcPkSqiqqHGc6nuu8/HnZCBl/sRAs3RfzP/rjcJ3NO5eOcB4dJf6Q5P1AjKvXY7Rd5nBZ8yrXzh@/QNfhX@4G2Mc/faIBIB3qfUMK6mCU4QXtwgXgAl4ju/wA)